# Как использовать django модели в стороннем python приложении?

Tags: python, django

У меня задача рассылать уведомления пользователям. Решил это делать с помощью скрипта на python, чтобы это реализовать, мне нужно обращаться к бд моего сервера. Хотелось бы этого использовать существующий файл моделий django.

к примеру main/models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email'),
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("Пользователь с такой почтой уже зарегистрирован.")
        },
        blank=True
    )

class Notification(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='notifications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

И хочу в стороннем скрипте делать подобные операции:

```
User.objects.filter(...)
Notification.objects.create(user=..., message=...)
```

Как правильно подключать настройки django и models.py в моем скрипте, чтобы это реализовать?

Мне это по большей части нужно для email рассылки напоминалки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы использовать модели проекта, нужно установить его окружение указанным ниже способом.

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("PYTHONPATH", "path/to/you/project")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "you_project.settings")
django.setup()
```

В дальнейшем, просто импортируете модель из своего проекта, и работаете с ней как обычно.